# Calculate the sum between the fixed time range using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks like this:

```
time                 Open      
2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.219690  
2017-01-01 01:00:00  1.688490  
2017-01-01 02:00:00  1.015285   
2017-01-01 03:00:00  1.357672  
2017-01-01 04:00:00  1.293786   
2017-01-01 05:00:00  1.040048   
2017-01-01 06:00:00  1.225080 
2017-01-01 07:00:00  1.145402  
...., .... 
2017-12-31 23:00:00  1.145402
```

I want to find the `sum` between the `time-range` specified and save it to new `dataframe`.

let's say,

- I want to find the sum between `2017-01-01 22:00:00` and `2017-01-02 04:00:00`. This is the sum of `6` hours between 2 days. I want to find the `sum` of the data in the `time-range` such as `10 PM` to next day `4 AM`  and put it in a different `data frame` for example `df_timerange_sum`. Please note that we are doing `sum` of `time` in 2 different date?

**What did I do?**

- I used the `sum()` to calculate `time-range` like this: `df[~df['time'].dt.hour.between(10, 4)].sum()`but it gives me `sum` as a whole of the `df` but not on the `between` `time-range` I have specified.
- I also tried the `resample` but I cannot find a way to do it for `time-specific`

Answer (score 0):

`df['time'].dt.hour.between(10, 4)` is always `False` because no number is larger than `10` and smaller than `4` at the same time. What you want is to mark `between(4,21)` and then negate that to get the other hours.

Here's what I would do:

```
# mark those between 4AM and 10PM
# data we want is where s==False, i.e. ~s
s = df['time'].dt.hour.between(4, 21)

# use s.cumsum() marks the consecutive False block
# on which we will take sum
blocks = s.cumsum()

# again we only care for ~s
(df[~s].groupby(blocks[~s], as_index=False)  # we don't need the blocks as index
       .agg({'time':'min', 'Open':'sum'})    # time : min -- select the beginning of blocks
)                                            # Open : sum -- compute sum of Open
```

Output for random data:

```
                 time      Open
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.282701
1 2017-01-01 22:00:00  2.766324
2 2017-01-02 22:00:00  2.838216
3 2017-01-03 22:00:00  4.151461
4 2017-01-04 22:00:00  2.151626
5 2017-01-05 22:00:00  2.525190
6 2017-01-06 22:00:00  0.798234
```

Comment: The data we want is between `10 PM - 4 AM` and not `4 AM - 10 PM`. Also in the final output, our `time` column should have `2017-01-01 - 2017-01-02` because the `Open_Sum` column is the `sum` between the hours of two days.

Comment: For the first question, remember that we negate `s`: `df[~s]` so yes, it is `10PM - 4AM`. For the second question, change `{'time':'min', 'Open':'sum'}` to `{'time':{'min','max'}, 'Open':'sum'}` inside the `agg` function.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, if the math worked :) now I get two-column header `time, time, Open_Mean` and `min, max, Open_Mean`. Could I just get 1 header? like, `time, Open_Mean` and have `date-range` inside `time`

Comment: I also just saw that the calculation is done in this way, `2017-01-03 04:00:00 - 2017-01-02 17:00:00` but I think we need to do it this way, `2017-01-02 17:00:00 - 2017-01-03 04:00:00` because we are going from `today time in PM` to `tomorrow time in AM`

Comment: Again, what does NEGATE do? Try the code on your data.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative (in my opinion more straightforward) approach that accomplishes the same thing..there's definitely ways to reduce the code but I am also relatively new to pandas

```
df.set_index(['time'],inplace=True) #make time the index col (not 100% necessary)
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['start_time','end_time','sum_Open']) #new df that stores your desired output + start and end times if you need them

df2['start_time']=df[df.index.hour == 22].index #gets/stores all start datetimes
df2['end_time']=df[df.index.hour == 4].index #gets/stores all end datetimes


for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.set_value(i,'sum_Open',df[(df.index >= row['start_time']) & (df.index <= row['end_time'])]['Open'].sum())
```

you'd have to add an if statement or something to handle the last day which ends at 11pm.